# Correctly catching async exceptions

Tags: python, exception

There is [asyncvnc](https://github.com/barneygale/asyncvnc) library, I use it in my code. This is a library for working with VNС servers.
But I had a problem with catching errors when connecting.
I need to ignore errors associated with connecting/sending/receiving data from the server, that is, all errors that are associated with communication with the server need to be ignored, I need to cause only those exceptions that are related to the library itself. Again, errors like unplanned disconnection from the server, connection timeout/waiting for a response from the server should be ignored.
For example, here is my code now:

```py
    result = False
    try:
        async with connect(host=host, port=port) as client:
            client: Client = client

            screen_first = await _get_screen(client)
            _send_keystroke_combination(client, ('ctrl', 'alt', 'del'))
            await asyncio.sleep(screen_delay / 1000)
            screen_second = await _get_screen(client)

            result = bool((screen_first != screen_second).any())

    except Exception as e:
        er = (str(e.__class__) + str(e.args)).lower()
        if "password" in er or "connect" in er or isinstance(e, (EnvironmentError, ValueError)) or str(e.__class__.__name__) in asyncio_exceptions:
            """
            ..note::
                This is not shitcode, it's just that there is no general exception in the library
                Ok, this is shitcode, but I didn't find a proper way to except the server connection or timeout error >:(
            """
            pass
        else:
            raise e

    return result
```

I really don't like this code, but the fact is that I don't understand how to properly separate errors related to communication with the server from the rest.
The library itself mostly uses `ValueError` exceptions, it would be possible to simply catch the `ValueError` exception, but the fact is that there may be exception calls from the asyncio library associated with timeouts, or for example another `OSError`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I interpret your question correctly, but maybe this helps: You can except multiple different Exceptions in a row and use the general `Exception` as a fallback catch-all.

For instance:

```
try:
    ...
    # try something
except TimeoutError as e:
    ...
except ConnectionResetError as e:
    ...
except ConnectionError as e:
    ...
except ValueError as e:
    ...
except OSError as e:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

Or if you want to do the same thing with 'e' for a couple of different Exceptions you can also shorten it like:

```
except (TimeoutError, ConnectionResetError, ConnectionError):
```

You find the builtin Exceptions here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Since you're using asyncio, you might also want to consider using an **ExceptionGroup** (see PEP 654) to handle several unrelated errors.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it is bad practice to use `except Exception as e:`.
This is bad because it will capture every exception - even if your program should have crashed instead.

The asyncVNC [library](https://github.com/barneygale/asyncvnc/blob/main/asyncvnc.py) directly raises two types of exception: `PermissionError` and  `ValueError`.

You probably want `PermissionError` to be raised, as this is due to an authentication error.

you can catch a specific exception using:

```
try:
    # your code here
except ValueError as e:
    # handle exception here
```

Docs for asyncVNC: https://asyncvnc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest